# Footer not in the correct place

Tags: html, css

Somehow, my HTML and CSS won't work properly. My main doubt is in the span. Because it's all working on any other pages.

The footer is not detecting any object, so it is staying at the most top of the page. (I've also tried putting the footer on the `<footer>` tag and it still shows the same result.)

The situation is illustrated in the picture that is attached.

Here is my code snippet:

```css
.aboutuspagetitle {
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(159,74,74,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 176px;
  left: 660px;
  font-family: Merriweather Sans;
  font-weight: Bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  opacity: 1; 
}
.aboutuspagedesc {
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 313px;
  left: 30px;
  font-family: Merriweather Sans;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 33px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.footer {
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #121212;
  font-family: Karla Tamil Upright;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300%;
}
.foot1{
  width: 304px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 568px;
  font-family: Karla Tamil Upright;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.foot2{
  width: 304px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 568px;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span class="aboutuspagetitle">ABOUT US</span>
  <span class="aboutuspagedesc">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut commodo nisl ut justo tincidunt, ac laoreet nunc elementum.</p>
  </span>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="foot1">THIS IS AN ADDRESS</p>
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><span class="foot2">© 2021</span></a>
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Put `bottom: 0` to your footer

Comment: You are using absolute positioning on basically every element on the page. I strongly recommend not using this approach, it's a very short road.

Comment: I guess you are learning how to code, please set your footer into a `<footer>` element. not a `<div class="footer">` That wont solve the problem, but that would be nicer code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to add `bottom: 0;` to the footer style. And position it using `position: fixed;` so it will stay at the bottom even when you scroll.

```css
.aboutuspagetitle {
  color: rgba(159,74,74,1);
  font-family: Merriweather Sans;
  font-weight: Bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.aboutuspagedesc {
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  font-family: Merriweather Sans;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 33px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
}
.footer {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #121212;
  font-family: Karla Tamil Upright;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0px;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.foot1{
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}
.foot2{
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="aboutuspagetitle">ABOUT US</h1>
  <span class="aboutuspagedesc">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut commodo nisl ut justo tincidunt, ac laoreet nunc elementum.</p>
  </span>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="foot1">THIS IS AN ADDRESS</p>
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><span class="foot2">© 2021</span></a>
  </footer> 
</body>
```

Here are some advices.
First, as said in the comments, don't use position absolute on everything !! As the moment you'll try a different screen size, everything will be offest.
Second, try not to add too many style that won't do anything at all at the end. If you try something and it doesn't work, remove it from the style !

Comment: You should probably add padding to the content so the bottom doesn't get clipped by the footer

Comment: Well, that's why, but I don't really want to make it stick when I scroll, so it's still okay to set the position to absolute right?

Comment: Oh wait, actually, it doesn't really solve it, because when I set some pages with more height, the footer is stuck on a place, what I meant is that the footer sticks to the bottom with any height of the page.

Comment: @Maple06, I've updated the answer with some more code. For your new problem, this shouldn't happen. Where is your footer in your code, directly in the body or in a container ?

Comment: Hi, it's directly in the body, also, I don't really want the footer to stay there when I scroll, so I think I need to change the position, but when I changed the position from fixed to another else it still stuck in the middle of the page.

Comment: @Maple06 Even with position absolute ? Normally, the only difference between absolute and fixed is the behavior when scrolling. For the body part, if your body doesn't make the size of the page, the footer will be positionned at the bottom of your body.

Comment: Yes, even with position absolute, indeed it is a bit strange, I just did some inspect and somehow the body height is not including the content in the body. So the footer did act normal, but the height of the body did not. Also thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Maple06 For the height of your body, it's because all of the content of it is in position absolute, so it won't make the height of the body change